# Game clips keep disappearing/getting deleted

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-one

For some reason, I've had problems with trying to keep funny moments and cool game captures on my Xbox One, as they keep disappearing. Just now, I was going to upload a funny clip so that it wouldn't get deleted yet when I got online - it's gone. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: I think clips are only ever deleted from xbox live automatically, and I'm not sure what the expiration is, but you're saying they're completely gone from your xbox as well?

Comment: Yes, it was there and then it got deleted the moment I connected to the internet. I disconnected and it still wasn't there and it deleted all my screen shots aswell.

Comment: Gotcha, just to clarify though, if you go to your captures, there is a dropdown menu to switch between "this xbox" and "xbox live". If you are sure you are looking at "this xbox" and they're not visible, that's definitely strange. I only suggest it because I have had clips fail to upload, and they're only found by using that dropdown, they appear to be missing by default.

Comment: Yeah they're gone even after switching from 'xbox live' to 'this xbox' :(

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://www.trueachievements.com/n35030/changes-made-to-xbox-one-gamedvr-captures-storage#:%7E:text=So%20that%20players%20use%20this,haven%27t%20got%20any%20views) page which states the following (as of October 2018):

> Players now have double the amount of storage space they used to have for Xbox Live Captures. So that players use this space efficiently, Microsoft will now be automatically deleting existing video clips over 90 days old that have no views. Any new clips recorded from this point onwards will be deleted after 30 days if they haven't got any views. Players can still back up their clips to a virtual drive or external storage before that expiration period

This would include your personal clips and it looks like they will need to be backed up to external storage or elsewhere in order to keep them.